# Convert JDialog to JPanel in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-platform, matisse

I spent a long time creating a nice Dialog using Netbeans (Matisse), and now I realise that I want it as JPanel instead.

Is there any way of converting the Dialog to Panel in Netbeans. The blasted GUI editor does not allow me to modify any of the code.

Comment: Just open navigator in design mode in jdialog, copy components and paste in jpanel view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open navigator in design mode in jdialog, copy components and paste in jpanel view.
Like in below image.

[image]

As always @MadProgrammer recommends, if you don't add directly to the jdialog and instead of a custom container (like a jpanel), then it's easy to put in another components :D

Comment: A follow-up to this: If you resize the new panel to a small size before copy/pasting, it will fit it to the old dialog's size. Whereas if the new panel is bigger than the old dialog, it will not resize.

Answer (score 1):

You can play a trick on Netbeans to convert it, with all your code:

Assuming your dialog class is called MyDialog:

1. In Netbeans UI Editor, create a new empty JPanel form (say, e.g.
   MyDialogPanel), and save it.
2. Quit Netbeans, and open your favorite
   file browser, navigate to the folder where your classes reside. You
   will find MyDialog.java and MyDialog.from - as well as
   MyDialogPanel.java and .form.
3. Now open MyDialog.java, and replace `JDialog` by `JPanel` in the class definition, and save as MyDialogPanel.java (overwriting the empty panel you have created).
4. Now open MyDialog.form, replace
   `JDialogFormInfo` by `JPanelFormInfo`, and save as
   MyDialogPanel.form (overwriting the empty panel you have created).
5. Open Netbeans, and open MyDialogPanel. The UI editor will be suprised and probably hickup a warning. Choose to allow editing, and save the dialog. Now look through your code, you probably need to fix a few things (like usages of getContentPane() or dispose() or the like, which are not there in a JPanel. After that, voila! Everything there, in your JPanel!

Answer (score 0):

Ah. Figured it out. Just need to create a JPanel Netbeans class. Then I can just copy and paste the components across from the JDialog by going into the navigator view.

Comment: exaclty what i comment xD

Comment: put it as an answer then i can +1 you :D